# Call a function in a DLL and use an array as argument

Tags: python, c, dll

I am calling a function from a DLL written in C. In the documentation of the DLL it says that one of the arguments of the function should be:

> an address of an array of 32-bit floating point
>                            numbers to be populated with results.

I am not really familiar with C and something tell me that this is a C feature. I am not quite sure what I should use for my argument.

I am using ctypes.

Here is an example from the documentation of the DLL:

> ```
>            float fResult;
>            long lRetVal = D2R_GetSingleResult(
>                              "E:\\Folder",
>                              "E:\\Folder\\Proj1",
>                              2001001, &fResult, 1, NULL, NULL );
> ```

Comment: Is there a prototype for this function in the docs?

Comment: You declare the array in your code something like float my_nums[32]; and then call the supplied function (say it's foo) like foo(my_nums);  But, why is this marked as a python question?

Comment: looks like `ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float)`

Comment: @fukanchik I have edited my original post

Comment: if I use ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float) I get a "Don't know how to concert parameter 4" error.

Comment: The address of an array is `int (*) arr[16]`. This example is a pointer to an array of 16 ints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I needed to defined the array argument as follow:

```
(ctypes.c_float*1)()
```

Thanks  @fukanchik for the help, you put me in the right path!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be to declare the function type to help `ctypes` deduce everything itself:

```
D2R = ctypes.cdll.LoadLibrary("d2r.so")
D2R_GetSingleResult = D2R.D2R_GetSingleResult
D2R_GetSingleResult.argtypes = (ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_char_p, ctypes.c_int, ctypes.POINTER(ctypes.c_float), ctypes.c_int, ctypes.c_void_p, ctypes.c_void_p)
D2R_GetSingleResult.restype = ctypes.c_int
...
fResult = ctypes.c_float()
lRetVal = D2R_GetSingleResult("Folder", "Folder\\Proj1", 2001001, fResult, 1, None, None)
```